# xsl picking text value of following siblings

Tags: xslt, dom, xpath

How can I get only **"Your friend"** or only **"Mickey Mouse"** from these nodes?

```
<span>
  <lb/>
  Your Friend
  <lb/>
  <name> Mickey Mouse </name>
</span>
```

My desired output from XSL would be this:

```
<p> Your Friend </p>
<p> Mickey Mouse </p>
```

---

I have tried with:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="./lb">
    <p>
        <xsl:if test="./following-sibling::text()[1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::*[text()][1]"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="./following-sibling::*[name]//text()">
            -test-
        </xsl:if>
    </p>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

but I know I'm completely wrong since I never get to -test-

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. You speak of "following siblings" - but the text node in `<name> Mickey Mouse </name>` is not a sibling of any other node.

Comment: I just need to get one paragraph with each text that follows an <lb> element, so:
<p>Your Friend</p><p>Mickey Mouse</p>

Comment: That's still not clear enough. A text node could be in another `span` or even further, and still be the first text that "follows an <lb> element".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mostly guessing here, but it seems you want:

```
<xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:for-each select="lb">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="(following-sibling::text()|following-sibling::name)[1]"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the output for this is: <p>Your Friend</p><p></p>

Comment: it only works because of the <xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> that you added there. But that answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Kyek Uhm, yes that is correct. Without it, the first text node is the one between   `<lb/>` and `<name>`. But you could also add a predicate using `normalize-space()` to ignore white-space-only text nodes.

Comment: Hey @michael.hor257k . Maybe you could edit your original answer with the correct version, since the hikmatu link you posted died 

Answer (score 0):

use code:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```